# Signing requests in Amazon S3 for .NET SDK through HTTP Header

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to access Amazon S3 content from a ASP.NET application. I am using AWS SDK kit for .NET. Currently, I am using GetpreSignedURL() function to sign my requests and then I am setting my IFrame src as the URL.

```
s3Placeholder.Text = ListingObjects();

GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest()
    .WithBucketName(bucketName)
    .WithKey("notebook.htm");

request.WithExpires(DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)));

string url = S3.GetPreSignedURL(request);    
this.Iframe2.Attributes.Add("src", url);
```

The issue is if you have a look at the source of the IFrame you can see the complete string including the access key and signature. I was wondering if there is a better way of doing it through HTTP headers so that the login secure information is not passed through query string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use http headers to authenticate the request so the only other potential option to is to proxy any requests through your web server but this gets complicated and removes many of S3's benefits.

However, what you are doing is not insecure. The pre-signed url **does not** expose your secret key. It only only shows your key (which does not need to be secret) and the signature (hash) which is generated using the secret key.

**You cannot work back from the url to get the secret key.**

You can make things even more secure by using [Amazons IAM](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) to create a user that only has readonly access to a single bucket and using those credentials to create your urls. That way, even if the attacker somehow manages to reverse engineer your secret key from the url, all they have is readonly access to a single bucket.